# SQL join: Join two tables to get the result from second tables to grep result and

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I want to grep the Employee Unique Tax ID from first Tables to second starting like:
[image]

```
select * from where Employee_ID as 'var1' Join on Employee_Catagory as 'var2' Join On Employee_Pos. as var3 .
```

To get the Employee Unique_Tax_ID as `$res` I want to have it in a Sigle SQL Statement. The var1 -var3 value is not important because that can I change with PHP in that file with functions.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: System_ID sorry I forgot to put that

Answer (score 0):

Simple `LEFT JOIN` should do:

```
select t1.employee_id,
    t1.employee_category,
    t1.employee_pos,
    t2.unique_tax_id
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.system_id = t2.system_id
```

Comment: Just to clarify @gurv the Unique_Tax_ID is not there every time and will be need later to change his Tax Level like from 1-6 in another Table.

Comment: @RidWan Change it to LEFT JOIN then.